# Scheduling a task whenever the system starts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, startup

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I want to create a task that mounts some of my Hard disk drives whenever the system starts. What Linux command can I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, why aren't they mounted automatically? Do you have them in `/etc/fstab`? Where they there when you installed the system?

Comment: I main problem is mount disk and filesystem I suggest editing `/etc/fstab`. You might user `@reboot` from crontab, beware this will bi started at the time cron start. eventually you have `init.d` script linked to `rcX.d` where X is run level given by `who -r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is mount some filesystems, list them in the file [`/etc/fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/fstab.5.html). Open the file in a text editor (you'll need to be root, you can use the command `sudoedit /etc/fstab`). Add a line at the end like this:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/windows ntfs-3g allow_other
```

The first column is the reference to the partition where the filesystem is. You can use one of three syntaxes:

- something like `/dev/sda1` (first partition of the first disk) to refer to a disk according to its discovery order and to a partition according to its numbering on the disk;
- `LABEL=wibble` if `wibble` is the label of the filesystem;
- `UUID=0123-abcd`  where `0123-abcd` is the output of `blkid /dev/sda1`.

The second column is the mount point. It must be an existing directory.

The third column is the filesystem type, probably `ntfs-3g` for a Windows filesystem.

The fourth column are mount options.

If you want to run commands other than mounting a filesystem, you have several options. Here are the main ones:

- To run a command at the end of the boot sequence, just before showing the text mode login prompt, create a file `/etc/rc.local`, put the commands you want in it:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  command1           # wait for it to terminate
  command2 &         # run it in the background
  ```

  Make the script executable:

  ```
  sudo chmod a+rx /etc/rc.local
  ```
- To run a command near the end of the startup sequence without delaying the boot prompt, run the command [`crontab -e`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/crontab.1.html) and add a [line](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/crontab.5.html) like

  ```
  @reboot somecommand
  ```

  The command will run under the account that you run `crontab -e` under.
- For fancier things, create an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) job.